# Не существует подходящей функции преобразования в "const char*"

Tags: c++, winforms, pascalabc.net

Начал переписывать задачу с PascalABC на C++ и столкнулся с ошибкой "не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>" в "const char *". А так же ошибка с min[i] - "слишком много аргументов функции". Делаю в формах Windows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                str = lines[a[i]];
                MarshalString(str, str2);
                name[i] = str2.substr(1, str2.find(' ') - 1);
                str2.erase(1, str2.find(' '));
                atoi(str2.substr(1, str2.find(' ') - 1), min[i], z); // Здесь ошибка
            }
```

Если нужно, могу привести код с Паскаля.

Answer (score 3):

`atoi` нужна C-строка.

Можно

```
atoi(str2.substr(1, str2.find(' ') - 1).c_str())
```

Только вот у вас `atoi` вызывается с тремя параметрами, в то время как это [функция от одного аргумента](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi), и возвращаемое ею значение вы игнорируете.

Но для `string` лучше воспользоваться функцией [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). Вот у нее действительно три аргумента :)

Comment: Но вот с функцией stoi уже перегрузка.